# Python: Error in re.compile() function for double digits

Tags: python, regex, pandas

This regex needs to find `"1x"` or `"x1"` but it must also be able find double digits such as `"10x"` and `"x11"`.

```
leverage_match = re.compile(r"\d+X|X\d+", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

According to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) the above regex should be sufficient to capture the entire numbers for:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(["BULL ESTOX 11X S", "BULL ESTOX X12 S"], columns=["name"])

name
"BULL ESTOX 11X S"
"BULL ESTOX X12 S"
```

However, for the code below it returns only one digit, e.g. for `"11X"` it becomes `"1X"`.

```
leverage_match = re.compile(r"\d+X|X\d+", flags=re.IGNORECASE) #<- Same as seen above

def f(value):

    f2 = lambda x: leverage_match.findall(x)[0] if len(leverage_match.findall(x)) > 0 else ""

    leverage = f2(value)

    if leverage != "":
        return "{}".format(leverage)

    if leverage[0].replace("X","x") == "x":
        leverage = leverage[1]+leverage[0].replace('X','x')

df["description"] = df["name"].map(lambda x:f(x))
```

### ----------

**Update**: This is the complete code, to assure I did not leave anything essential out:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(["BULL ESTOX 11X S", "BULL ESTOX X12 S"], columns=["name"])

description_map = {"ESTOX":"Euro STOXX 50"}
underlying_match = re.compile(r"\s(\S+)\s")
leverage_match = re.compile(r"\d+X|X\d+", flags=re.IGNORECASE)

def f(value):

    f1 = lambda x: description_map[underlying_match.findall(x)[0]] if underlying_match.findall(x)[0] in description_map else ""
    f2 = lambda x: leverage_match.findall(x)[0] if len(leverage_match.findall(x)) > 0 else ""
    f3 = lambda x: "-" if "BEAR" in x else "-" if "SHORT" in x else ""

    underlying = f1(value)
    leverage = f2(value)
    sign = f3(value)

    statement = "Tracks " + underlying

    if underlying == "":
        if sign == "-" and leverage == "":
            return statement + "{}".format("inversely.")
        if sign == "-" and leverage != "":
            return statement + "{} with {}{} leverage.".format("inversely", sign, leverage)
        if sign == "" and leverage != "":
            return statement + "with {}{} leverage.".format(sign, leverage)
        else:
            return "Tracks"

    if leverage[0].replace("X","x") == "x":
        leverage = leverage[1]+leverage[0].replace('X','x')

    if leverage != "" and sign == "-":
        statement += " {} with {}{} leverage.".format("inversely", sign, leverage)
    elif leverage != "" and sign == "":
        statement += " with {} leverage.".format(leverage)
    else:
        if sign == "-":
            statement += " {} ".format("inversely")

    return statement

df["description"] = df["name"].map(lambda x:f(x))

print df
```

Comment: try `re.compile(r"\b\d+X|X\d+\b", flags=re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks, but that gives identical result to the current regex. It only grabs `"1"` not `"11"`.

Comment: Your code works for me, I get `11X` and `X12`

Comment: @EdChum Did you run the code in an interpreter or just check the regex?

Comment: I ran this in ipython: `In [279]:

df = pd.DataFrame(["BULL ESTOX 11X S", "BULL ESTOX X12 S"], columns=["name"])
​
df["description"] = df["name"].map(lambda x:f(x))
df
Out[281]:
               name description
0  BULL ESTOX 11X S         11X
1  BULL ESTOX X12 S         X12`

Comment: @EdChum That is weird. I have updated the question with a more complete set of code to make sure I didn't leave anything essential out.

Comment: @Winterflags , what is your expected output when u print `df`?

Comment: This makes no sense, the `+` should be greedy according to the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you gave a wrong example, for the following `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["BULL AXP 11X S", "BULL AXP X11 S"], columns=["name"])
```

The output will be as follows

```
             name                                 description
0  BULL AXP 11X S  Tracks American Express with 11X leverage.
1  BULL AXP X11 S   Tracks American Express with 1x leverage.
```

and `x11` becomes `1x` because there is an error in the logic of our your code in the following section:

```
if leverage[0].replace("X","x") == "x":
        leverage = leverage[1]+leverage[0].replace('X','x')
```

It must instead should have been as follows:(**UPDATE**)

```
if leverage[0].replace("X","x") == "x":
        leverage = ''.join(leverage[1:])+leverage[0].replace('X','x')
```

If you fix that , the Output will be as you expected and will be as follows:

```
             name                                 description
0  BULL AXP 11X S  Tracks American Express with 11X leverage.
1  BULL AXP X11 S  Tracks American Express with 11x leverage.
```

**COMPLETE CODE**

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(["BULL ESTOX 11X S", "BULL ESTOX X12 S"], columns=["name"])

description_map = {"ESTOX":"Euro STOXX 50"}
underlying_match = re.compile(r"\s(\S+)\s")
leverage_match = re.compile(r"\d+X|X\d+", flags=re.IGNORECASE)

def f(value):

    f1 = lambda x: description_map[underlying_match.findall(x)[0]] if underlying_match.findall(x)[0] in description_map else ""
    f2 = lambda x: leverage_match.findall(x)[0] if len(leverage_match.findall(x)) > 0 else ""
    f3 = lambda x: "-" if "BEAR" in x else "-" if "SHORT" in x else ""

    underlying = f1(value)
    leverage = f2(value)
    sign = f3(value)

    statement = "Tracks " + underlying

    if underlying == "":
        if sign == "-" and leverage == "":
            return statement + "{}".format("inversely.")
        if sign == "-" and leverage != "":
            return statement + "{} with {}{} leverage.".format("inversely", sign, leverage)
        if sign == "" and leverage != "":
            return statement + "with {}{} leverage.".format(sign, leverage)
        else:
            return "Tracks"

    if leverage[0].replace("X","x") == "x":
        leverage = ''.join(leverage[1:])+leverage[0].replace('X','x')

    if leverage != "" and sign == "-":
        statement += " {} with {}{} leverage.".format("inversely", sign, leverage)
    elif leverage != "" and sign == "":
        statement += " with {} leverage.".format(leverage)
    else:
        if sign == "-":
            statement += " {} ".format("inversely")

    return statement

df["description"] = df["name"].map(lambda x:f(x))

print df
```

Comment: That may be it, although hat gives me error `IndexError: string index out of range`.

Comment: @Winterflags , I think you might get that error if you had only single digit in your data right?

Comment: @Winterflags , I updated the answer to prevent such errors, check it :)

Comment: That did the trick :) Thanks for spotting the error and your update :)